# Get select value on load and apply regex

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML `select` with options (months), and I use that select for filter data text in a `div` element. That filter is a simple regex with JS.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyadaro/tykuehxa/

Note the `selected` value in the *January* `option`. That's dynamic (I get the info from a database).

**Problem:** I need the select to apply that regex when the document (or body) is loaded. Not only on `select` change.

---

```
<select name="" id="date_filter">
    <option value="0">All months</option>
    <option value="01/2017" selected>January 2017</option>
    <option value="02/2017">February 2017</option>
    <option value="03/2017">March 2017</option>
</select>

<div class="date">
    <p>19/01/2017 17:39</p>
</div>
<div class="date">
    <p>19/02/2017 17:36</p>
</div>
<div class="date">
    <p>18/01/2017 20:40</p>
</div>
<div class="date">
    <p>18/02/2017 13:31</p>
</div>
<div class="date">
    <p>18/03/2017 13:17</p>
</div>
<div class="date">
    <p>18/03/2017 13:15</p>
</div>
```

---

```
$("#date_filter").on('load change', function() {
    var month = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    console.log("month: "+month);

    var pattern = new RegExp(month, "i");

        $('body').find('.date').each(function() {
            if (($(this).children('p').text().search(pattern) <= 0)) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            if (($(this).children('p').text().search(pattern) >= 0)) {
                $(this).show();
            }
            if (month === "0") {
                $(this).find('.date').show();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: you can't have "load" event on select or input elememt. it is valid only in case of iframe or img tag etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the event after defining it. either by using `.trigger()` or `.change()`:

```
$("#date_filter").on('change', function() {
       //rest code here
}).change();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxg6n6jc/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap up the event listener in a function and also call it on page load:

```
$("#date_filter").on('load change', update);

$(document).on('ready', update);

function update() {
    var month = $(this).find(":selected").val();

    console.log("month: "+month);

    var pattern = new RegExp(month, "i");

    $('body').find('.date').each(function() {
        if (($(this).children('p').text().search(pattern) <= 0)) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        if (($(this).children('p').text().search(pattern) >= 0)) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        if (month === "0") {
            $(this).find('.date').show();
        }
    });
}
```